# Regex : How to start lookup from the end of string

Tags: regex, uppercase, right-to-left

I want to get **all** characters **until** there is an **uppercase** but from the **end** to the start. (or right to left)

> blab blab 12 34  This is a test!

I need `This is a test!`.

This is what I have managed to find:

```
^.*?(?=[A-Z])
```

But it returns `blab blab 12 34`

Comment: @rubberboots Yes! I was struggling how to use the dollar sign. Omg it was very easy...! Thanks! If it's possible add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I see, Yossi's anwer came up earlier, so he won the game. I'll accept defeat ;-)

Comment: @rubberboots How is that his answer didn't show up ? I was continuously refreshing the page and didn't see it. Anyway sorry, I marked his answer as accepted. If not it would be unfair. but I upvoted yours as well :D

Comment: I'm an old f**t and getting slow over the years ;-) So **it's fine** the young hearts get the loot (if they deserve it ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
irb(main):001:0> regex = /([A-Z][^A-Z]*)$/
irb(main):002:0> "blab blab 12 34 This is a test!".match regex
=> #<MatchData "This is a test!" 1:"This is a test!">
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll add that as an answer, probably developing it into other variants later. The easy solution should be sth. like:

```
 [A-Z][^A-Z]*$
```

test (in Perl):

```
 print $1 if 'blab blab 12 34 This is a test!' =~ /([A-Z][^A-Z]*)$/;
```

returns:

```
 This is a test!
```

To solve this, the pattern needs to be *anchored* at the end of the string (`$`).

Regards

rbo